# Array of strings, wildcards and wget

Tags: arrays, bash, wildcard, wget

What I'm trying to do is get some specific files from a directly through FTP with wget. I want to get the files using an array of strings and using wildcards combined with the array to choose which files are obtained.

Example of what I mean:

I have an array

```
arr[0]=a

arr[1]=b
```

There is a bunch of files in the directory dir which I am connecting to using wget and I want all the files that start with a or b (the strings in my array).

So I tried the following:

```
wget $dir${arr[@]}*
```

it will get all the files that start with "a" but then tries to connect to

```
"http://b*/".
```

So it looks like if I added the directory to each element of the array it could work, however that isn't an ideal situation.

I'm currently working in a Windows build of Cygwin but will me moving to some Unix machines soon.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating strings and arrays rarely has the desired effect. Use a for loop instead:

```
arr=(a b)
for var in "${arr[@]}"
do
  wget "$dir$var*"
done
```

You can also get something akin to your code with parameter expansion:

```
dir="ftp://host/dir/"
arr=(a b)
arr=( "${arr[@]/%/*}" )       # append asterisks
echo wget "${arr[@]/#/$dir}"  # prepend dir
```

prints `wget ftp://host/dir/a* ftp://host/dir/b*`.